# Extracting Player Hyperlinks from Basketball Reference Column(From Tables With Multiple Columns of Hyperlinks) to new Column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I recently asked a very similar question to this, however, I have run into some additional issues regarding the problem. My goal was to extract the links from the column column players to new column with rows corresponding to the given player. My current method works for some tables where these links are the first to appear in the table. However, with tables like the one in the code below, there are links prior to the player ones and those are what come through to the new column. I have attempted to exclude certain links from the ones extracted using sub strings. However I am unclear on what format the "list"(not as in a list object) of links are coming is as. Does anyone know of a way to either extract soley the player links? I cannot find any obvious differences between the columns' links within the html so I am unclear if this is even possible. However, if anyone more knowledegable of BeautifulSoup could take a look, that would be amazing.
Below I have provided the code, the type of links coming in, and the desired links. Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 
import unicodedata


def MVPWINNERS():
        url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html"
        html = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        tabs = soup.select('table[id*="mvp_NBA"]')
        for tab in tabs:
            cols, players = [], []
            for s in tab.select('thead tr:nth-child(2) th'):
                cols.append(s.text)
            for j in (tab.select('tbody tr, tfoot tr')):
                player = [dat.text for dat in j.select('td,th') ]
                player_links=(j.find('a')['href'])

                player.append(player_links)



                players.append(player) 

        max_length = len(max(players, key=len)) 
        players_plus = [player + [""]*(max_length - len(player)) for player in players]
        df=pd.DataFrame(players_plus,columns=cols+["player_links"])

        max_length = len(max(players, key=len)) 
        players_plus = [player + [""]*(max_length - len(player)) for player in players]
        df=pd.DataFrame(players_plus,columns=cols+["player_links"])
        print(df)

MVPWINNERS()
```

Current output:
/leagues/NBA_2022.html

Desired Output:
/players/j/jokicni01.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    players = set(urljoin(url, x['href'])
                  for x in soup.select('td[data-stat=player] a'))
    pp(players)


main('https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html')
```

Output:

```
{'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulka01.html',
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/antetgi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/barklch01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/birdla01.html',    
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bryanko01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/chambwi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cousybo01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cowenda01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cunnibi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/danieme01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/duncati01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/duranke01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/e/ervinju01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/g/garneke01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/g/gilmoar01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hawkico01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/haywosp01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/i/iversal01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/johnsma02.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jokicni01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/m/malonka01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/m/malonmo01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/m/mcadobo01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/m/mcginge01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/n/nashst01.html',    
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/n/nowitdi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/o/olajuha01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/o/onealsh01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/p/pettibo01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/reedwi01.html',    
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/roberos01.html',
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/robinda01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/rosede01.html',    
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russebi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/u/unselwe01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/w/waltobi01.html',   
 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/w/westbru01.html'}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick and helpful response. I think your method is heading in the right direction, however, it only returns one of each, not accounting for players who have won multiple times. In addition, the links seem to be coming in order not the same as the original table. This may be able to be solved by applying some sort of string analysis but I do not believe this will work due to the similarities of many player links given the structure. Also just figured I would mention it. I do not require the full link. Just the suffix.Thank you for your time and help.